# Creating roles and granting rights to the role

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, users, role

I wanted to create a role called "user_updates" and this role should have the rights "table_note_updates".
The rights called "table_note_updates" is already available in my database. How to grant the rights to role that i create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A role can be granted to another role.

```
create role user_updates;
grant table_note_updates to user_updates;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create role user_updates;
grant table_note_updates to user_updates;
```

***Grant created role to user.***

```
grant user_updates to myuser;
```